# Using Marquee ProgressBar in installation preparation

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

is it somehow possible on the WizardForm.PreparingPage to display a ProgressBar in Marquee style? We have the problem with one of our setups that the preparing process takes quite a long time (~ 15-20 seconds). So sometimes it seems like the setup got hung up there.

I have already tried with a ProgressBar, whose parent is the WizardForm.PreparingPage, as well as with the [OutputMarqueeProgressPage](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createoutputmarqueeprogresspage), which should be displayed instead of the PreparingPage. Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to clearly determine when the preparing is through and when to move to the next page.

I'm already through several posts, but can't find a suitable solution....
This is how I initialize the "new" preparing page:

```
procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  ProgressPage := CreateOutputMarqueeProgressPage('Prepare installation..', '');
  WizardForm.PreparingPage.Visible := False;
end;
```

This is how I call up the page currently:

```
function GetTickCount: LongWord;
  external 'GetTickCount@kernel32.dll stdcall';

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
var
  StartTime: LongWord;
begin
  if (CurPageID = wpPreparing) then
    begin
      ProgressPage.Show;
      try
        StartTime := GetTickCount;
        while (GetTickCount - StartTime) < (10 * 1000) do
        begin
          ProgressPage.Animate;
          Sleep(50)
        end;
      finally
        ProgressPage.Hide;
        ProgressPage.Free;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I know myself that it is very unsightly, as here, test, for ten seconds the display should be shown - how can I clearly determine when it should no longer be displayed?

Thank you!

Comment: You didn't tell us anything about the "step".

Comment: How do you mean "the step"?

Comment: I don't have any additional code that is performed during the "PrepareToInstall"-Event, if that's what you meant. I just want that during the preparation process (whatever is being prepared there, am not in the topic there unfortunately), a ProgressBar is displayed until the preparation is complete to signal to the user that the setup is still "alive".

Comment: How can we help you with *"when it should no longer be displayed"* when we do not know how that step is implemented? If I do not miss anything, your current `CurPageChanged` code does not run in parallel with the step at all. It runs pointlessly for given number of seconds, blocking the installer meanwhile.